# bash zip by file permissions

Tags: bash, permissions, zip

I have a "zipup.sh" routine that backs up to one zip file. It includs file paths of all my programs in several different Linux folders within my home directories with an `-mtime -1`.

At times, I write little snippets in the /common directory, which is shared by the entire team. Large common files are stored there, which we all share, but we do not share whatever code we post there.

If I don't restrict to just my files, I get everyone's junk in my daily zip files as team members are not disciplined in cleaning up after themselves.

Is that possible in bash zip v6.0?

Research into zipping and file permissions reveals some answers saying it would be a two-step process, (such as copying all my /common code to a temp folder and including that folder in zipup.sh), which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to do something like:

```
find /common -type f -executable -print0 | exec xargs -r0 zip yourcode.zip
```

You can of course add other args to `find` (last modification date, etc...)